Stray symbols appearing in WordPress byline after upgrade to 6.5.2
I’m trying to solve a minor but really annoying glitch after upgrading to WordPress 6.5.2. Specifically, several random characters are now appearing in the byline for each blog post on my website, per the screen shot shown. That is, these characters now appear to the immediate right of every byline:      ‘, “); ?>

I’m using the Twenty Twelve theme, ver. 1.5. This theme has been customized a bit, but it was working fine prior to the upgrade. I’m pretty sure there’s a new glitch in the CSS code, but I can’t find the offending line(s). Any suggestion/guidance, if only on which theme file to look at, would be greatly appreciated!!!

Turns out that it was some conflict with the version of PHP I was using. I upgraded to 8.0, which seemed to generate the extra characters. As a test, downgrading to 7.4 or upgrading to 8.1 (the latest version) fixed the issue... partially. Using PHP 8.1 removes the extra characters on the summary version of each post, but when you click “Continue reading” the extra characters show up at the bottom. Partial solution is progress, but more R&D is needed.
